# How can i know its valid in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am developing an Adobe interactive form with LiveCycle LC designer with JavaScript.

// Identify required fields (it may be a free text field, drop-down, check box, i mean there 3 kinds possibilties) and make yellow colored them

```
var myArrayYellow = new Array(); 
var yellowFields;  
yellowFields = my_required_fields_list_string.rawValue  
myArrayYellow = yellowFields.split(" "); 
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayYellow.length; i++)     {
```

**===> Here at this point, i want to check the existence of [i] field in the form that its a valid field/objetc or not? bcz, i have chances of getting non-existing fields in the my_required_fields_list_string, hence prior to assigning yellow color to them, i want to check their validity on the form or not?**  **Pls. let me know the JS for this**     // if its true/found, then only assign yellow color as below

```
    xfa.resolveNode("MY_ADOBE_FORM.." + myArrayYellow        [i]).ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "255,255,254"
};
```

For some other purpose, some expert gave me a JS as below, i tried to tune it as per my above requirement, but its not working

```
function findNodes(vNode){
    if (vNode.className === "field"){
        if (vNode.isPropertySpecified("name") === true){
            var myStateName = new RegExp(vNode.name);
            var returnValue = GFL.search(myStateName);
            if (returnValue != -1) {
                this.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "192,192,192";
                this.access = "readOnly";
            } else {
                this.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "255,255,255"; //whatever colour is open access
                this.access = "open";
            }
        }
    }
    for (var a=0;a<vNode.nodes.length;a++) {
        findNodes(vNode.nodes.item(a));
    }
}
findNodes(xfa.form);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your problem, you need to check if `xfa.resolveNode` returns something and handle it from there.

```
var node;
if ( (node=xfa.resolveNode("MY_ADOBE_FORM.." + myArrayYellow[i]) )!==null){
    node.ui.oneOfChild.border.fill.color.value = "255,255,254"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to check if all of your values in the array are valid before preforming operations on them. Just check and make sure they are not null.

**EDIT: You should probably check for empty string as well.**

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArrayYellow.length; i++)     {
    if (!(myArrayYellow[i] == null || myArrayYellow[i] == "")){
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```